# Order-preserving map between $X^*$ and $\mathbb N$ for some finite set $X$

Tags: order-theory

Let $X = \{ 1, \ldots , r \}$ be $r$ symbols with $1 < 2 < \ldots < r$ and define on the set of all finite sequences $X^*$ the lexicographic ordering as given [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Ordering_of_sequences_of_various_lengths). Is it possible to establish an order preserving (i.e. monotone) bijective mapping between $X^*$ and $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Literally two lines after the definition of the order it says that it is ***not*** a well-order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've seen two yeses so far. The answer is no. Hint: A natural number has only finitely many predecessors. (Or: there are only finitely many natural numbers between any two natural numbers.)

Comment: To be fair, the yeses were both correct but based on a different definition of "lexicographic ordering".

Comment: I also pointed this out in a comment that the answer is "no" for the alternative definition of lex ordering that seems to be the one used here, based on the responses I got to my answer.

Comment: Yes. Although to be fair to me, the OP did specify the definition he meant. I've never seen that other ordering called "lexicographic" (it's not called that in that Wikipedia article either). Not that standard usage is a guide to mathematical terminology, but the order I'm talking about is the one that _is_ "lexicographic". It's the ordering in dictionaries. "zebra" comes _after_ "something".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have an ordering on $X$, and if you are familiar with different base expansions of natural numbers, then all you have to do is identify each string in $X^*$ with the number the string represents when interpreted as a base-$r$ expansion of a number. If $r > 1$ is an integer, the base $r$ representation/expansion of a natural number is unique, and in bijective correspondence.

Comment: Why is this an *order preserving* bijection, though? (HINT: It's not.)

Comment: Nope. Say we have two symbols, $1$ and $2$. Take $b=10$. Now in the lexicographic order we have $(1,2,2) < (2,1)$. So you're saying that $122 < 21$. Not true.

Comment: I went to the link and I read about ordering by LENGTH first, in which case what I'm saying is true. Maybe I didn't read the right part of the link though.

Comment: Furthermore, if an arbitrary length string starting with "1" is considered less than the string of one character "2", then there is no order preserving isomorphism with the natural numbers, because every subset of natural numbers has a least element. We could consider "12","112","1112" etc. and this has no least element.